# AWS: How to point out a certain folder that appsec.yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I have the following structure of the repo

```
tree repo_name 
repo_name
└── subfolder
    └── appsec.yml
```

AWS CodeDeploy and CodeBuild exects YAML files in the root folder while this is not the case for me. Is there anyway to set a folder for YAML file and run Codebuild and Deploy?

Answer (score 2):

For CodeBuld you can use [alternative location and name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-name-storage) for `buildspec.yml`. But for CodeDeploy there is no such option. `appsec.yml` must be in root. Thus in your build stage you can copy your `appsec.yml` from your subfolder to root to workaround this limitation.